# How to use variable string in index formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, vlookup

I want to refer to another workbook while writing INDEX Formula in VBA. These are the steps I am following:

dim myFilePath as String, myFileName as String, mySheetName as string

1. myFilePath = inputbox("Write the path")
2. myFileName = inputbox ("Write the name")
3. mySheetName = inputbox ("Write the sheet name")
4. Range("CA1").Select
       ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=INDEX('myFilePath[myFileName]mySheetName'!R1C1:R100C1,MATCH(RC[-53],'myFilePath[myFileName]mySheetName'!R1C8:R800C8,0))"

However, the formula is not accepting the variables myFilePath, myFileName and mySheetName. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: How can you ask to match `RC[-53]` when you are in A1?

Comment: My Bad. It is CA1. (EDITED) Anyways, I am stuck at how to use the variable strings in the INDEX formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like,

```
Range("CA1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=INDEX('" & myFilePath & "[" & myFileName & "]" & mySheetName & "'!C1, MATCH(RC[-53],'" & myFilePath & "[" & myFileName & "]" & mySheetName & "'!C8, 0))"
```